Can I track the number of messages deleted due to retention policy in an SQS queue?
We have setup our queue with a retention time of 20 minutes (because we just timeout tasks).
I would like to track how often these timeouts happen, is there any way to do that using cloudwatch metrics for SQS or do I have to add new metrics to my existing code?

I don't see it in the listed SQS metrics here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html
